# Python Bottle.py decorator confusion

Tags: python, decorator, bottle

i have a decorator named "auth"

```
def auth(check_func=validate_login):
    def decorator(view):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            auth = check_func()
            if auth:
                return view(*args, **kwargs)
            return bottle.redirect('/login.html')
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

the `auth` decorator is used like this

```
@get('/')
@view("someview")
@auth()
def handler():
   #myhandlercode
```

so the `auth` decorator calls the `view` function which renders my template in bottle.py.
But now i want to return json instead of rendering a `view`. So what changes do i have to make to the `auth` decorator code to make this happen? I am confused as to how to call the handler instead of the `view` from the auth code.

EDIT 1 : Bottle allows you to return dict, it directly converts it to json. And i dont want to use the view at all, i just want to return json to the user from my handlers.  So should i just remove the @view decorator? and what should i call instead in the auth decorator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bottle route decorators are able to apply decorators to you without destroy auto json feature.

```
@get('/', apply=[auth])
def handler():
    ...
```

If you don't want a view, just remove your `@view` decorator, Bottle handle dicts gracefully, converting it to a JSON answer.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe its right to have auth shoehorning in json dumping.

Here's an example with plain ol python of using decorators

```
def validate():
    return True

def auth(valid=validate):
    def _auth(f):
        def _auth_wrap():
            if not valid():
                raise Exception('redirect')
            return f()
        return _auth_wrap
    return _auth

def view(tmpl):
    def _view(f):
        def _view_wrap():
            return tmpl.format(f())
        return _view_wrap
    return _view

@view('Hello, {0}')
@auth()
def handler():
    return 'World'

handler
# outputs: __main__._view_wrap
handler()
# outputs: 'Hello, World'
```

and also the line

```
return tmpl.format(f())
```

The `f` func is `__main__._auth_wrap` which is calling validate and returning the executed handler.

so then you would handle dumping json by doing something else besides tmpl.format in the above, such as calling a seperate method and passing needed info, or shoehorning into view decorator, which either way will be more appropriate.

So to answer the end question a little better, if you want to dynamically decide whether or not to dump json based on the request and bottle.py's view func doesn't support this, then you could make a view wrapper similar to the above that does the checks on the request object or whatever you want to use to determine json output, and then either call bottle.py's view or json.dumps on `f()` within _view_wrap

If you want to make a func always dump json, then delete the view decorator and create a json decorator similar to the view decorator above that will `return json.dumps(f())`

The main point here is to keep auth doing what it's name implies.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning Json (or rather a python dictionary) from your view, right? In that case you don't have to change anything in the decorator. That which the view returns is not immediately forwarded to the user's browser, it is first processed by bottle then returned to the user. When you return a dictionary from the view it is treated as Json, when returning a template string it is treated as Html.